# Running PowerShell via x64 in Jenkins

Tags: java, windows, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I’m a Jenkins newbie but really want to see how Jenkins can help me in our build pipeline. As a part of our requirement, we need to be able to invoke PowerShell scripts via the x64 instance. I've got Jenkins installed on Windows Server 2012 R2 and out of the box, the PowerShell plugin worked fine but via the x86 engine. As I’ve learned, by default, Jenkins uses the x86 version of Java. No problem. I’ve installed the x64 version of Java, modified Jenkins.xml to look like this:

```
<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe</executable>
```

…and restarted the Jenkins service. The service restarts fine but the web interface is unresponsive. I’ve tried to reboot the entire server, set the JAVA_HOME system environment variable to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131` and uninstalled the x86 version of Java to no avail.

From what I've been reading, this works for most people but not for me. I've also looked at the jenkins.err.log and jenkins.out.log files to see any indication why I'm getting no response from the web interface and they have nothing in them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adam, I think your correct except the entry would require quotes. Here is what I have in my very PowerShell oriented Jenkins and all works as expected.

```
<executable>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe"</executable>
```

64 bit Java and 64 bit PowerShell, as you require.

**UPDATE:**

Here is my scrubbed but accurate full jenkins.xml. I've never had to set JAVA_HOME, maybe something is picking that up and getting confused. Aside from altering the executable to an external JVM (64bit) and some --https* parameters added I've not done anything extraordinary to the config and like I said its been happily working for awhile.

```
 <service>
  <id>jenkins</id>
  <name>Jenkins</name>
  <description>This service runs Jenkins continuous integration system.</description>
  <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>
  <!--
    if you'd like to run Jenkins with a specific version of Java, specify a full path to java.exe.
    The following value assumes that you have java in your PATH.
  -->
  <!--<executable>%BASE%\jre\bin\java</executable>-->
  <executable>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe"</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --webroot="%BASE%\war" --ajp13Port=-1 --httpPort=-1 --httpsPort=8443 --httpsListenAddress=192.0.0.192 --httpsKeyStore=C:\MyJavaKeyStore.jks --httpsKeyStorePassword=PasswordToSaidJKS</arguments>
  <!--
    interactive flag causes the empty black Java window to be displayed.
    I'm still debugging this.
  <interactive />
  -->
  <logmode>rotate</logmode>

  <onfailure action="restart" />
</service>
```

You might try un-commenting the `<interactive />` node to see what errors might be thrown but possibly not logged.

Comment: I tried that but the service wouldn't start then. :/

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround , you can use the Execute Windows batch command instead of Windows powershell and call the x64 powershell like below

```
"C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -noprofile -file "<Folder Path of file>\Psscript.ps1" -<Parameter> "<Parameter value>"
```

Comment: I thought of that but it's not a sustainable solution. I'd rather just get this to work and from what I've been reading it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just getting frustrated and copying the x64 JRE into the C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jre folder and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the windows firewall "allowed executable" in the programs/services tab from the exe in the Jenkins directory to the new java.exe in the 64 bit directory.

I noticed that if I ran Jenkins in localhost:8080 on the remote machine, everything ran fine. Only remote machines couldn't connect.